# basic alias for quote literal

Tags: bash, unix

Can anyone be of help why this is giving me errors and not working at my `~/.bashrc`.

greatly appreciated:

```
alias ferr='grep ^ \'ERRROR\' '
```

trying to get ferr to find all lines that starts with `^ ERROR` (note: space between `^` and `ERRROR`).

I tried this too but didn't seem to work:

```
ferr() {grep ^' ERROR' "$@"}
```

this is probably one of those of course that is the problem moments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
alias ferr="grep ^ERRROR"
```

To include the space before ERROR try:

```
alias ferr="grep \"^ ERRROR\""
```

Comment: It works here in `GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems. Inside of single ticks `\` has no effect. So the shell sees: `grep ^ \` followed by `ERROR' '`. That means the shell only sees three of the four ticks and it wonders where the last one went.

Next, I don't think that `^` is a valid argument to `grep`. Try `"^ ERROR"` (and make sure you get the number of `R`s right, too).

And if you want to match something at the start of a line, use

```
alias ferr="egrep '^pattern'"
```

where pattern is what you look for. This becomes more complex if the pattern really contains `^`. For sake of simplicity, I suggest to search:

```
alias ferr="egrep '^. ERROR'"
```

i.e. search for any line that starts with anything, followed by space, followed by the word `ERROR`

Comment: "egrep '^. ERROR'" that is actually pretty smart. ^ works but you need to use grep ^' ERROR' *.log

Comment: `^' ERROR'` works because the shell only separates words by spaces. As long as you string quotes together, everything will be a single word.

Answer (score 0):

use `alias ferr='grep -E "^ERROR"'`
then to search all lines starting with ERROR, just use `[bash]$ ferr <filename>`.

To search with a different string replace what's inside `"`